# OpenGL ES Sphere alpha texture exported from Blender

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, textures, alpha, blender

I am using OpenGL ES 1.1 in iOS 5.0 , and I want to draw a sphere with a texture mapped.
The texture will be a map of the world, which is a .png with an alpha channel.
I want that to see the other part of the globe by the inside.

However, I obtain this strange effect and I don't know why this is happening.

I'm exporting from Blender using this script: https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Blender%20Export/objc_blend_2.62

I've already tried to reverse the orientation of the normals but it didn't help.

I don't want to activate culling because I want to see both faces.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/screenshot20121207at308.png/

Comment: not that i know it, but maybe you need to texture outside AND inside of the sphere, just a thought though